# jquery add input fields before Ajax output

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I know this is complicated and I am a complete newbie to jscript and AJAX, so please be gentle because I'll get it.  I've come a long way in 2 days.

I have a GET API that builds the AJAX output as it goes, doing a document.write at the end.   That works great.
Now I need to add search functionality above the AJAX output - if I put it in the HTML, it literally gets written over when the document.write output occurs, so I put it after Success but before the Ajax output.  It does display but I am not having much success making it work and my time is very short on this project, so if you can help, I'd really appreciate it.

I had to do a lot of editing on this code to put it here, but it works (except for the Search Zip input field and Submit button).

```html
<html xmlns="//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml "> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Rent Properties</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#dvLoading
{
   /*background:#000 url("/images/loading.gif") no-repeat center center;*/
   height: 230px;
   width: 600px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 10%;
   top: 50px;
   margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
   
}
#Search
{
   background-color:#f0f0f0; 
   height: 40px;
   width: 600px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 10%;
   top: 0%;
   margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
   
}
#Properties
{
   background-color:#f0f0f0; 
   height: 40px;
   width: 600px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 10%;
   top: 50px;
   margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
   
}
</style>

<div id='dvLoading'><font style="font-size:3em"><i>Loading ... Please be patient.</font></i><br><br></div>
 <!--<p id='Search' style='vertical-align:top'><table style='background-color:silver;padding:6px'><tr><td>Zip: <input type='text' name='zip' id='zip'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' id='getdata-button'>Submit</a><br></td></tr></table><BR><BR>-->
  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json_obj = "";
    var json_obj2 = "";
    var json_obj3 = "";
    var output = "";
    var VProp = "";
    var Prop = "";
    var URL2 = "";
    var URL3 = "";
    var Img0 = "";
    var Img = "/images/ImgNF.png";
    var propblk = [];
    var zip = "";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;

// !!!! Trying to get Search Zip here
        $('#getdata-button').click(function () {
            zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
            document.write("Zip: " + zip + "<BR>");
        });
     
        $.ajax({           
            url: "http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxxx.aspx?requestType=apartmentavailability&companyCode=xxxxxx",
            dataType: "text",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            crossDomain: true,

            success: function (data) {
                    output = "<p style='vertical-align:top'><table style='background-color:silver;padding:6px'><tr><td>Zip: <input type='text' name='zip' id='zip'><a href='#' id='getdata-button'>Submit</a><br></td></tr></table><BR><BR>";  // I know - this should be in CSS but not sure how to incorporate it
               document.write(output);
               json_obj = $.parseJSON(data); 
                for (var i in json_obj)
                {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        output = "<center><table id='Properties' style='background-color:#4A4C4E;text-align:center;width:90%;position: fixed;z-index: 10;left: 3%;top: 52px;' width='90%'><tr>"
                        output += "<td width='30%' style='background-color:green;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding:12px'><font style='color:white;font-family:Verdana'>";
                    }
                    else {
                        output = "<td width='30%' style='background-color:green;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding:12px'><font style='color:white;font-family:Verdana'>";
                    }
                    VProp = json_obj[i].VPropCode;
                    URL2 = "http://api.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxapi.aspx?requestType=property&type=propertyData&companyCode=xxxxxx&VPropCode=" + VProp;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: URL2,
                        dataType: "text",
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            json_obj2 = $.parseJSON(data);
                            Prop = json_obj2[0].PropertyCode;
                            var zipcode = json_obj2[0].zipcode;

                            var fnd = -1;
                            if (zip == "") { fnd = 0; }
                            else { fnd = zipcode.search(zip); }

                            if (fnd >= 0) {
                                json_obj3 = "";
                                URL3 = "http://api.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxapi.aspx?requestType=images&type=propertylmages&companyCode=xxxxx&propertyCode=" + Prop;
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: URL3,
                                    dataType: "text",
                                    async: false,
                                    cache: false,
                                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                                    crossDomain: true,
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        json_obj3 = $.parseJSON(data);
                                        if (json_obj3[0].ImageURL) {
                                            Img0 = json_obj3[0].ImageURL;
                                            output += "<center><A href=renttest2.htm?Prop=" + Prop + "><img src='" + Img0 + "' width=250 height=168></a></center><br>";
                                        }
                                        else { output += "<center><A href=renttest2.htm?Prop=" + Prop + "><img src='" + Img + "' width=250 height=168></a></center><br>"; }
                                    },
                                    error: function () {
                                        output += "<center><A href=renttest2.htm?Prop=" + Prop + "><img src='" + Img + "' width=250 height=168></a></center><br>";
                                    }
                                });

                                output += json_obj2[0].address + "<BR>" + json_obj2[0].city + ", " + json_obj2[0].state + " " + json_obj2[0].zipcode + "<BR>Floor Plan:  " + json_obj[i].FloorplanName + "<BR>Bedrooms: " + json_obj[i].Beds + "<BR>Baths: " + json_obj[i].Baths + "<BR>Sq Ft: " + json_obj[i].SQFT;
                                output += "<br><center><table style='border:1px solid black;background-color:gray;padding:4px'><TR><TD><A href=renttest2.htm?Prop=" + Prop + " style='color:white;font-family:Arial;'>Detail</a></td></tr></table></td><td width='3%'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";
                                if (i == 2 || i == 5) { output += "</tr><tr>"; } // I know how to check "divided by" in PHP but not jscript - I can figure that out
                                propblk[i] = output;
                           }

                        },
                       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            document.write("Status2: " + textStatus);
                            document.write("Error2: " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

               }
// starting to set up for paging, 6 per display
                for (x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
                    if (propblk[x]) {
                        document.write(propblk[x]);
                    }
                }

                output += "</td></tr><tr><td colspan=10><br>End of Data</td></tr></table></center></p>";  
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                document.write("Status: " + textStatus);
                document.write("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }

        });
    });


</script>
</head>
    <body>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put it in your question

Comment: Sorry I can't give out the confidential link to test with, but I'm just looking for how to structure the input and output.  I can give you a test page if there is a way to do that securely.

Comment: Instead of using document.write, I would recommend creating an empty div (or other object) with an id, then using jQuery to target that node and writing the html directly to that node using     $('#myDiv').html(output)

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example of how to do that - or a link?
Again, complete newbie.

Comment: Just create the html document as normal, and add a <div id="myDiv"></div> where you want it.  When use $('#myDiv').html(output); in place of document.write(output);  You'll need to do a bit of styling and such but it is a starting place.

Comment: @nurdyguy that worked out fine.  How do I give you credit & close this?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer instead of a comment, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I normally do place an empty div somewhere on the document and then use the result of the AJAX to create the html code to fill the div.

```
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

You've already got the html code in your output variable so then use

```
    $('#myDiv').html(output);
```

This will replace all of the html inside of the div with what you put in output.  If you don't want to replace it all but rather just add some more to the end of the div (like adding 1 row to the bottom of a table) then use

```
    $('#myDiv').append(output)
```

You'll still need to style and place the div where you want.  This is one very common way of dealing with your situation.